# My validate form js is showing empty first time and works the second time

Tags: javascript, php

In my code I use a rich text editor. I have a text box set for that editor and have a function in the form to validate the form to be sure nothing is left blank.

When the form is submitted, it always says that the HTML text box is empty, I click the OK button and click save again and it saves. In other words, it has to be saved 2 times in order for it to stop the popup saying it's empty.

What can I do to make it so if it's empty it shows the popup and if something is in the text area it saves?

Here is some of my code:

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["subject"].value;
  var y = document.forms["myForm"]["html_email"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("You Did Not Enter A Subject Line");
    return false;
  }
  if (y == "") {
    alert("You Did Not Create The Body Of The E-Mail");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="emails" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<input style="width: 500px;" type="text" name="subject" value="$subject" placeholder="Subject Line" required>
  <textarea class="ckeditor" name="html_email" required>$html</textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-success" id="sendme" value="Save Email" />
</form>
```

I am using ckeditor.js in order to make it a rich text editor.

The "required" is not working as it should so it lets a blank save occur. So I must use this JS to check it to be sure it's not blank.

Comment: why you don't want to use a framework? you just can save a lot of time.

Comment: Where is the `subject` field in the form?

Comment: You don't need you own validation function for this. The `required` attribute does the same thing.

Comment: I can't see anything in this code that would cause the problem you describe. Are you sure the alert is coming from this?

Comment: for some reason, the Required is not working as it should and it allows for a blank save.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I have no idea what framework is or how to use it for a form.

Comment: @Barmar yes the alert is coming from this. Here is what the alert says on the first save: "You Did Not Create The Body Of The E-Mail". Then I click the OK button on that alert and click "SAVE" again and it saves it.

Comment: It's not working because you initialize the textarea with `$html`. Use a placeholder if you want to display a message when the user hasn't entered anything.

Comment: @Barmar I changed the code and took out the $html and it's still showing that alert. I will just change to checking it before it saves it and take them back to the page if anything is blank with an error message.

Comment: Actually, that initialization should allow the form to be submitted even if they haven't entered anything. I can't see any reason why it's not working. Do you have any AJAX submission code?

Comment: @RandyThomas you can use something [tiny and simple](https://redom.js.org/#todomvc) to make your life easier

Comment: @Barmar no I don't have any AJAX being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```html
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["subject"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("You Did Not Enter A Subject Line");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The `required` attribute in your form will already check if the textarea is not empty and show an alert.

It's also recommended to do server side validation as the javascript / html can be manipulated on the client side.

Comment: for some reason, the Required is not working as it should and it allows for a blank save.